# Recovering from Datastore commit exceptions for transactions that are not idempotent

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The Google App Engine documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions says this:

> Note: In extremely rare cases, the transaction is fully committed even
>   if a transaction returns a timeout or internal error exception. For
>   this reason, it's best to make transactions idempotent whenever
>   possible.

What is the proper way to recover from a commit exception if the transaction is not idempotent?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is show the end user an error with a link they can use to view the state of their world.  Then the end user can decide whether to resubmit.  E.g. if they post a comment to a blog and the post somehow reports an error, they can re-load the blog page and see if their comment is there; if they see it's not, they can (hopefully) recover it from their browser history and resubmit.

Comment: What if the action being recorded is something important, like a payment?

Comment: Well, for the user it's not so different from the situation where they hit "Send" on a payment and then their internet connection suddenly goes down.  When it comes back up, they'll have to log back in and check whether the payment happened or not.  You should design your webapp to support that use case -- the same approach will also help the user recovering from these "extreme rare cases".  (FWIW, I've never heard from an App Engine user to whom this actually happened.)

Comment: Maybe for such an important transaction you can programmatically verify the state of your data manually on failure, instead of putting the stress on your user : something like catching the error and verify that the data has been written with a query. The feasibility depends on the complexity of the process occuring in your transaction. Something like a payment is pretty easy to detect though, even more if you manually assign your entity identifiers. This question is basically : "how can I detect if I need to ignore a fake datastore failure"